# Connect to a remote service which uses a self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, arangodb

I'm trying to connect to a remote arango database (which uses a self signed certificate while in development) from a Firebase cloud function. It gives the following error.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to avoid this error? Can I upload certificates to cloud function server?

ArangoJs has a method to use self signed certifications(below image). But the problem is how to copy these certs to the cloud so that the files can be accessed by the cloud functions.

[image]

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried to add process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; line. But firebase deploy fails when I do that.

Comment: @DougStevenson After multiple tries it worked suddenly. Thanks. It seems this is a duplicate question after all.